# What Is The PostgreSQL Equivalent To SQL Server NVARCHAR?

Tags: postgresql

If I have fields of NVARCHAR (or NTEXT) data type in a Microsoft SQL Server database, what would be the equivalent data type in a PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Please do not assume that everybody knows what "NVARCHAR/NTEXT" in MS SQL. If you want to get real information - you have to provide more information - what this datatype is. I have personally no idea what this datatype is, what it can store (texts, i guess), what are its limits, and so on.

Comment: @depesz - sorry, they are Unicode character strings.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271(SQL.80).aspx for definitions.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I'm pretty sure postgres varchar is the same as Oracle/Sybase/MSSQL nvarchar even though it is not explicit in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/datatype-character.html

Encoding conversion functions are here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#CONVERSION-NAMES

Example:

```
create table
nvctest (
utf8fld varchar(12)
);
insert into nvctest
select convert('PostgreSQL' using ascii_to_utf_8);
select * from nvctest;
```

Also, there is [this response](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2004-04/msg00321.php) to a similar question from a Postgresql rep:

> All of our TEXT datatypes are
>   multibyte-capable, provided you've
>   installed  PostgreSQL correctly.
>   This includes: TEXT (recommended)
>   VARCHAR CHAR

Comment: This answer is wrong.
Try e.g. 

    o = JSON.parse('{ "a": "\\uD83D", "b": "\\uDE01" }');
    o.a + o.b

in a browser console.  Then try to store the individual properties o.a and o.b into a postgres TEXT/VARCHAR   and a SQLServer NVARCHAR.   Retrieve them ( or concatenate them in the database ) and inspect the result. Multibyte capable does not imply the ability to store half surrogate pairs, as Postgres only offers a UTF-8 character set.  See the lengthy post below.

Answer (score 24):

Short answer: There is no PostgreSQL equivalent to SQL Server NVARCHAR.

The types of NVARCHAR(N) on different database are not equivalent.
The standard allows for a wide choice of character collations and encodings/character sets. When dealing with unicode PostgreSQL and SQLServer fall into different camps and no equivalence exists.

These differ w.r.t.

1. length semantics
2. representable content
3. sort order
4. padding semantics

Thus moving data from one DB system (or encoding/character set) to another can lead to *truncation/content loss*.

Specifically there is *no equivalent* between a PostgreSQL (9.1) character type and SQL Server NVARCHAR.

You may migrate the data to a PostgreSQL binary type, but would then loose text querying capabilities.

(Unless PostgreSQL starts supporting a UTF-16 based unicode character set)

1. Length semantics

---

N is interpreted differently (Characters, Bytes, 2*N = Bytes) depending on database and encoding.

Microsoft SQL Server uses UCS2 encoding with the VARCHAR length interpreted as UCS-2 points, that is length*2 = bytes length ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 ):
their NVARCHAR(1) can store 1 UCS2 Characters (2 bytes of UCS2).
Oracle UTF-encoding has the same semantics ( and internal CESU-8 storage).

Postgres 9.1 only has a Unicode UTF-8 character set (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/multibyte.html) , which, like
Oracle (in AL32UTF8 or AL16UTF16 encoding) can store 1 full UCS32 codepoints. That is potentially up to 4 bytes (See e.g
http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-nvarchar2/  which explicitly state the NVARCHAR2(50) column may take up to 200 bytes).

The difference becomes significant when dealing with characters outside the basic multilingual plane which count as one "char unit" in utf8 ucs32 (go, char, char32_t, PostgreSQL ), but are represented as surrogate pairs in UTF-16 which count as two units ( Java, Javascript, C#, ABAP, wchar_t , SQLServer).

e.g.
U+1F60A SMILING FACE WITH SMILING EYES  will use up all space in SQL Server NVARCHAR(2).
But only one character unit in PostgreSQL.

Classical enterprise grade DBs will offer at least a choice with UTF-16 like semantics (SAP HANA (CESU-8), DB 2 with collation, SQL Anywhere (CESU8BIN), ...)
E.g. Oracle also offers what they misleadingly call an UTF-8 Collation, which is effectivly CESU-8.
This has the same length semantics, representable content as UTF-16 (=Microsoft SQL Server) and is a suitable collation used by UTF-16 based enterprise systems ( e.g. SAP R/3 ) or under a Java application server.

Note that some databases may still interpret NVARCHAR(N) as a length in byte limitation, even with a variable length unicode encoding ( Example SAP IQ ).

2. Unrepresentable content

---

UTF-16 / CESU-8 based system can represent half surrogate pairs, while
UTF-8/UTF-32 based system can not.
This content is **unrepresentable** in this character set, but are a frequent occurrence in UTF-16 based enterprise systems.
(e.g. Windows pathnames may contain such non-utf-8 representable characters, see e.g. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12056).
Thus UTF-16 is a "superset" of UTF-8/UTF-16 which is typically a killer-criteria when dealing with data from enterprise/os-systems based on this encoding ( SAP, Windows, Java, JavaScript ). Note that Javascript JSON encoding took specific care to be able to represent these characters  (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#page-10 ).

(2) and (3) are more relevant when migration queries, but not for data migration.

3. Binary sort order:

---

Note that binary sort order of CESU-8/UTF-16 is different than UTF-8/UTF-32.

UTF-16/CESU-8/Java/JavaScript/ABAP sort order:

```
U+0041  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
U+1F60A SMILING FACE WITH SMILING EYES
U+FB03  LATIN SMALL LIGATURE ffi
```

UTF-8 / UCS-32 (go) sort order:

```
U+0041  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
U+FB03  LATIN SMALL LIGATURE ffi 
U+1F60A SMILING FACE WITH SMILING EYES
```

4. Padding semantics

---

Padding semantics differ on databases esp. when comparing VARCHAR with CHAR content.

Comment: I have seen mentions of unpaired surrogates not being considered "valid" UTF-16. But this doesn't alleviate the problem since most UTF-16-accepting databases do not validate UTF-16 prior to storing it; in accepting "unvalidated UTF-16" (or WTF-16, as I've seen called) still results in contents non-representable in UTF-8.

Answer (score 13):

It's *varchar* and *text*, assuming your database is in UNICODE encoding. If your database is in a non-UNICODE encoding, there is no special datatype that will give you a unicode string - you can store it as a bytea stream, but that will not be a string.

Answer (score 8):

Standard TEXT datatype is perfectly fine for it.

Answer (score 3):

Necromancing - wtf, no real answer since 2009 ? 
The postgresql equivalent for nvarchar is

```
national character varying(length)
```

This, by the way, is part of the sql-standard and works on sql-server, too.

By the way, for `nvarchar(MAX)` the PostgreSQL equivalent is

```
national character varying
```

(without any length specification and no parentheses - note that omitting the length for an nvarchar(MAX) does not work on sql-server)

If nvarchar doesn't work with your version of postgresql, you can create a domain.

```
CREATE DOMAIN datetime AS timestamp without time zone; 
CREATE DOMAIN nvarchar AS national character varying; 
CREATE DOMAIN uniqueidentifier AS uuid;
```

Comment: I upvoted, but I think this just to make one feel better and it is just  character varying.

Comment: Cetin Basoz: Yes it is. Postgresql doesn't differentiate between varchar and nvarchar. Which encoding it uses depends on which encoding you set on the database. nvarchar just exists as a keyword because of sql-standard-compliance. Actually, if you set the db encoding to utf8, this is far better than what MSSQL is doing. Besides, all the N' for working with nvarchar is a garbage idea IMHO.

Comment: Well not only a garbage idea, but now giving me a grief when I try to import SQL server data into postgreSQL with Citus. I can read it into a postgreSQL table via FDW fine, but trying to insert the same data into Citus distributed data I get ".... is not a valid UTF8 sequence" errors. That is a Citus extension issue but now my problem at the end :)

Comment: do you export to a sql-script ? 
If you did you should encode the files with utf8, and add a utf8 byte-order mark.

Comment: No, I didn't export to a script. It would take ages that way. Citus is in a docker container, I have created an FDW wrapper to SQL server using odbc_fdw and doing a insert into ... select .. from fdw_Table ... 
Probably, when I have time, I would export data from SQL server to .CSV files and work with COPY instead. At this moment, I don't understand why the same insert into ... select ... from fdw_Table  command works, only if destination is not a Citus distributed table.

Comment: @Cetin Basoz: Might also be an issue with the locale or the encoding in the template database. Try to create the db from template0. CREATE DATABASE badchars ENCODING 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'   LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8' TEMPLATE template0;

Comment: OK, I will try that later. If it improves anything I will let you know. At this moment I don't know how I could do that for Citus docker image (I also have a linux VM where I install Citus extension myself, I can check there).